# Xamarin Access to the path is denied PNG

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, xamarin.android

Another day and still can't run my first ever Xamarin.Android project. Not surprising, right?

So, here's how my activity's axml looks like :

```
<LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight=".3"
        android:background="@mipmap/bk_home_top"
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout1"/>
```

(Yeah, i know it's a HelloWorld). Anyways, when i try to build the project, i get 3, sometimes 4 errors.

> Access to the path "bk_home_top.png" is denied.
>
> The "CopyIfChanged" task failed unexpectedly.(a big error pointing to the same file)
>
> The "LinkAssemblies" task failed unexpectedly.(Hope you gusseted which file it's pointing to).

Already tried:

- Opening the file in paint and saving it back

Still no luck. Can someone atleast explain to me why it can't access the file?

Here's an easter-egg.

"**The project successfully build sometimes! No Errors! No Access Issues! But as soon as i close the emulator and try to run it again, Wallah! Hope you guessed it.**

Any fixes?

Comment: I don't think that this is reproducible. While I understand that you are seeing that thing, you should assume (and as you have quite level of points you should know that) that Xamarin is used by multi-billion dollar companies, and it can build the Android project in normal situations. So possibly you need to clean the project, create the new project, if you are using VS 2019 as it is fresh switch back to VS 2017, clean packages, reinstall VS... but again hardly anyone can provide you any specific help and this question should be closed IMHO.

Comment: @IvanIčin, hardly anyone can give me any solution? Seriously? And i am really asking myself why Xamarin is used by such big companies...! I love C#, that's why i chose Xamarin. But now, after spending 48 hrs with my first hello world project, i can't even run it on a real device but only in the emulator. And after this issue, i can't even run it in the emulator anymore. Can you give me some hints on why this might be happening?

Comment: As said this doesn't happen on the new device with the clean installed Windows on clean installed Visual Studio on the clean project. So find what is wrong by eliminating one by one, you have the issue somewhere, I already gave you the hints.

Comment: @IvanIčin, the issue is now gone as i opened the project in VS 2017

Comment: I’ve suggested that new versions of VS frequently have problems nowdays so don’t hurry in installing them.

Comment: @IvanIčin, yes, i just wonder why, after almost 4 months of preview release, they have received tons of bug reports and after so long, they fixed the bugs and released VS 2019 and yet i already submitted 3 bug reports! One thing i don't yet understand is that a billion $$ company like MSFT, even after acquiring Xamarin, still hasn't improved the product yet. Xamarin.Android came out almost 9-10 years ago and devs still face the same issues they faced back then. If you visit the forums, you would see one common comment, "What the hell are the official devs of Xamarin doing ?"!!!

Comment: @IvanIčin, hey, can you take a look at my new issue [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55553587/xamarin-java-exe-exited-with-code-1-proguard-issue) ?